# i want to simplify this javascript code how can i do

Tags: javascript

i dont want to keep repeat Almost the same code

look like this

[codepen](https://codepen.io/lechan87/pen/LYrmQaW)

```
const text01_edit = document.querySelector(".text01_edit");
const input_text01 = document.querySelector(".text01_contain");

const text02_edit = document.querySelector(".text02_edit");
const input_text02 = document.querySelector(".text02_contain");

// txt
const txtFunction = function (txt) {
  txt.disabled = false;
  txt.setSelectionRange(txt.value.length, txt.value.length);
};
text01_edit.addEventListener("click", function () {
  txtFunction(input_text01);
});

text02_edit.addEventListener("click", function () {
  txtFunction(input_text02);
});
```

if i need add more  (ex:text3 、text4)

i just can only add more like this?

or have something can simplify this code.
i try to use this in my function but it doesn't work , maybe use for?

Please let me know if you don't understand english is not my language ！

Comment: Use an array instead of enumerating variable names

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class attribute to all the inputs to which you want to add this event listener. Let's say you added the class `text-input` then you would do the following:

```
const textInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".text-input");
textInputs.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', txtFunction )
})
```

The `querySelectorAll` returns an array of matched elements, we then loop over them add attach the same function as the event listener.

Comment: thanks i go try it

Comment: Great to hear, can you accept the answer as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help,**

```js
var textbtn = document.querySelectorAll(".textbtn");

for (i = 0; i < textbtn.length; i++) {
  textbtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table class=" table table-hover text-nowrap">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>text</th>
        <th>btn</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="text01" value="text" disabled="true">
        </td>

        <td>
          <label class="textbtn" data-id="text01">click</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="text02" value="text" disabled="true">
        </td>
        <td>
          <label class="textbtn" data-id="text02">click</label>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: some explanations about your approach would've made your answer more readable, helpful and accessible to anyone who sees it.